# Cannot use MSSQL Timestamp as a parameter in Delphi XE8

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2012, delphi-xe8

We are in the process of upgrading one of our projects from Delphi XE to XE8. Our audit code makes use of a TIMESTAMP field in a MSSQL (2012 in this instance) database and selects from a table using this as a parameter in the WHERE clause.

We now are no longer getting any results running the following code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADODataset1.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM CURRENCYAUDIT';
  ADODataset2.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM CURRENCYAUDIT WHERE Audit_Timestamp = :Timestamp';
  ADODataset2.Parameters.Refresh;

  ADODataset1.Open;
  if ADODataset1.FieldByName('audit_timestamp').IsNull or ADODataset1.IsEmpty then
  begin
    showmessage('nothing to compare');
  end;

  ADODataset2.Parameters[0].Value := ADODataset1.FieldByName('audit_timestamp').Value;
  ADODataset2.Open;
  caption := inttostr(ADODataset2.RecordCount);
end;
```

Where CurrencyAudit is any old MSSQL table containing an notnull timestamp audit_timestamp field.

The caption of the form is 0 with no message shown.

Any idea how I can get this to work? Tried AsString (nonsense string, 0 results), AsSQLTimestamp (parameter doesn't accept) and AsBytes (0 return). Unfortunately the return of the `.Value` only evalates as 'variant array of byte' which isn't helpful to visualise/see what it is.

Edit: Running it as .AsBytes and viewing that in the debugger I can see that the XE verison is returning 0,0,0,0,0,8,177,22 whereas the XE8 is returning 17,32,0,0,0,0,0,0. Checking other fields of the (real) database shows the record is the same. Looks like a bug in reading TIMESTAMPs from the DB

Comment: Have you tried `.AsDateTime`?

Comment: @JerryDodge TIMESTAMP is a misnomer - it's not a TDateTime, it's more like a global autoinc field. Just a a quick check, it doesn't work as TBytesField can't be converted. As TIMESTAMP is an 8-byte number I also tried AsLargeInt, which doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using two AdoQueries.  The following works fine for me in D7, correctly returning 1 row in AdoQuery2, but 0 records in XE8, so obviously has the same XE8 problem as you've run into.

```
var
  S : String;
  V : Variant;
begin
  AdoQuery1.Open;
  S := AdoQuery1.FieldByName('ATimeStamp').AsString;
  V := AdoQuery1.FieldByName('ATimeStamp').AsVariant;
  Caption := S;
  AdoQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('ATimeStamp').Value := V;
  AdoQuery2.Open;
```

Just for testing, I'm running my AdoQuery1 and AdoQuery2 against the same server table.

**Update :**  I've got a similar method to the one in your answer working that avoids the need for your Int64ToByteArray, at the expense of some slightly messier (and less efficient) Sql, which may not be to your taste.

In my source AdoQuery, I have this Sql

```
select *, convert(int, atimestamp) as inttimestamp from timestamps
```

and in the destination one

```
select *  from timestamps where convert(int, atimestamp) = :inttimestamp
```

which of course avoids the need for a varBytes parameter on the second AdoQuery, since one can pick up the integer version of the timestamp column value and assign it to the inttimestamp param.

Btw, in your original q

```
  if ADODataset1.FieldByName('audit_timestamp').IsNull or ADODataset1.IsEmpty then
```

the two expressions would better be written the other way around.  Unless ADODataset1 has persistent fields, if it contains no records when opened, referring to the audit_timestamp should raise a "Field not found" exception.

Comment: This in XE8? Just using Parameter.Value := Field.AsVariant is still returning nothing for me. Post-edit - yes, this was only a quick 'demonstrate to show that it's not due to no data' bit of demo code. There's nothing like this in production

Comment: Yes, this is working in XE. I'm suspecting the optimisation work on TField

Comment: Yes, if I can keep it all server-side it seems to be fine. I think the problem is converting the value into a ByteArray - the number is completely different in XE vs XE8 (see edit to q). My current plan is to try to cast it down as an int64 and then use that. MSSQL can cope with it in dynamicSQL, but not as a parameter back to the original table as it has a type mismatch :-/

Comment: Just posted an update with an alternative work-around that avoids handling timestamp values on the Delphi side.

Comment: Going to go for your solution rather than mine, as it puts the onus on Microsoft rather than me to deal with the edge-cases! Should also be a bit more resilient for future breakages/fixes from EMBT side.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that EMBT have broken the conversion of a TIMESTAMP into a byte array. The XE version of the bytearray is correct and manually pulling down the data as an int64 and then building the bytearray by hand (is there an out-of-the-box function for this?) and using that as the parameter works in XE8.

I've no idea whether this is a similar issue with other binary data types. Hope not!

Working code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestArray: TArray<Byte>;
  j: integer;
  function Int64ToByteArray(const inInt: uint64): TArray<Byte>;
  var
    i: integer;
    lInt: int64;
  begin
    SetLength(result, 8);
    lInt := inint;
    for i := low(result) to high(result) do
    begin
      result[high(result)-i] := lInt and $FF;
      lInt := lInt shr 8;
    end;

  end;

begin
  ADODataset1.CommandText := 'SELECT  *, cast(audit_timestamp as bigint) tmp FROM CURRENCYAUDIT';
  ADODataset2.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM CURRENCYAUDIT WHERE Audit_Timestamp = :Timestamp';
  ADODataset2.Parameters.Refresh;

  ADODataset1.Open;
  if ADODataset1.FieldByName('audit_timestamp').IsNull or ADODataset1.IsEmpty then
  begin
    showmessage('nothing to compare');
  end;

  ADODataset2.Parameters[0].Value := Int64ToByteArray(ADODataset1.FieldByName('tmp').asInteger);
  ADODataset2.Open;
  caption := inttostr(ADODataset2.RecordCount);
end;
```

I've also checked this going down my entire (real) table and ensuring all other fields match to make sure it's not a one-off!

I'll raise a ticket with EMBT for them to sit on and ignore for 5 years ;-)

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11644